# How can we use ReLU activation in a Normalizing Flow model? More generally, is differentiable almost everywhere enough for a normalizing flow?

Tags: distributions, neural-networks, normalizing-flow, relu, differentiable

In some works, e.g., [enter link description here](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v108/kong20a/kong20a.pdf)
normalizing flow models are considered with ReLU activation.
For example, using a planar flow, $f = f_n \circ ... \circ f_1$, and each $f_i$ has the form
$$ z\mapsto z+uh(w^Tz + b)$$
for fixed vectors $u, w$, fixed scalar $b$, and activation function $h$.
Further, it says in  [Kong et al.](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v108/kong20a/kong20a.pdf)

> A ReLU planar/Sylvester flow is invertible under certain bounds on its parameters as ReLU is Lipschitz.

It is a fundamental property that normalizing flow models are invertible and differentiable. So if we let $h(z) = ReLu(z) = \max(0, z)$, then the neural network may be 1-1, but clearly will not differentiable.

Is the reason that this is "ok" because the non-differentiable set is measure 0?

If so, can we extend normalizing flow models to the class of invertible functions that are differentiable almost everywhere?